# Cassandra - .db files bigger than actual data

Tags: cassandra, diskspace

We're currently switching cassandra (2.x to 3.11.1) and when I exported the data as plain text (as prepared INSERT statements) and checked the file size I was shocked.

The actual data size in txt was 11.7GB.
The actual file size of all .db files is 127GB.

All keyspaces are configured with compaction SizeTieredCompactionStrategy and compresseion LZ4:

```
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
```

So why are the files on the disk 10x bigger than the real data? And how do I shrink those files to reflect (kinda) the real data size?

Just a note: all data is simple time-series with timestamp and values (min, max, avg, count, strings, ...)

The schema:

```
CREATE TABLE prod.data (
datainput bigint,
aggregation int,
timestamp bigint,
avg double,
count double,
flags int,
max double,
min double,
sum double,
val_d double,
val_l bigint,
val_str text,
PRIMARY KEY (datainput, aggregation, timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (aggregation ASC, timestamp ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 1.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Thanks all!

**UPDATE**

- add schema
- fix cassandra version (3.1 => 3.11.1)

Comment: 3.1? you mean 3.11? either go with 3.0.latest or 3.11.latest atm - 3.1 very risky

Comment: Please include your schema